# Passing variable from if to else in java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

Defined `a` variable in `if` loop and need to pass the value updated in `else if` loop. Example :

```
if(document.getVersionIdentifier().getValue().equals("00"))
{
    String a=attrs.put(CREATED_BY, shortenFullName(document
                            .getCreatorFullName()));
    // Value a = USer1
}
else if(document.getVersionIdentifier().getValue().equals("01"))
{
    String b = attrs.put(document,a);
    // Need value of b to be User1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your question makes no sense. If the `if` statement is executed, the `else if` will be ignored hence passing on any data from the `if` body to the `else if` body is irrelevant.

However, what you can do is changing the `else if` to a separate `if` statement and define `a` outside of the `if` bodies. In principle this could look like this - needs tweaking as per what you really want (unclear from your question).

```
String a = null;
if(document.getVersionIdentifier().getValue().equals("00"))
{
    a = attrs.put(CREATED_BY, shortenFullName(document.getCreatorFullName()));
    // Value a = User1
}

// The value of a can be either null or set during the if statement above.
// If a has a value the next if statement will always be false so the value of a
// will be always null if the next if statement is true.
if(document.getVersionIdentifier().getValue().equals("01"))
{
    String b = attrs.put(document,a);
    // Need value of b to be User1
}
```

Comment: Note that the code doesn't make any sense as written; if the first `if` is executed, the second one won't be, unless `getVersionIdentifier().getValue()` is able to return different values when called twice.  So `a` can never be anything other than `null`.  So this definitely needs tweaking.

Comment: Agreed. Added more code documentation to make this clear.